# How do I fix my code for my recursive countdown python function so that it only prints “LIFT OFF!’ once?

Tags: python, function, recursion, time

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

def countdown(num):
  if num <= 0:
    return num
  else:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(num)
    countdown(num - 1)
    print(“LIFT OFF!”)
```

Comment: Your code contains numerous syntax errors. Please post the actual code you're running.

Comment: `if num <= ):` make this `if num <= 0:`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my error, so now how do I print “LIFT OFF!” once?

Comment: You do `print(“LIFT OFF!”)` if `num` is not `0`. You might want to print it only if `num == 0`.

Comment: When you're making the recursive calls to `countdown(n - 1)` you still have the command `print(“LIFT OFF!”)` waiting to be executed in every level of your recursion. As @lenik has put in their answer, you should remove it from where you have put it to somewhere it will only execute once.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time

def countdown(num):
  if num <= 0:
    print('LIFT OFF!')
    return num
  else:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(num)
    countdown(num - 1)
```

here's the output:

```
>>> countdown(4)
4
3
2
1
LIFT OFF!
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want `lift off` to print once, then print it once:

```
import time

def countdown(num):
  if num <= 0:
    return num
  else:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print(num)
    countdown(num - 1)

countdown(5)
print('LIFT OFF!')
```

Output:

```
5
4
3
2
1
LIFT OFF!
```

Now the `countdown()` function does just one thing, which is print numbers after a delay.